# How to avoid doing dishes (after microwaving food)

Tags: cleaning, food, efficiency

So if I put a dish in the microwave, is there a way to avoid getting the plate dirty so I don’t have to worry about doing dishes? I was thinking stuff like french fries, pizza variations (bite sized, melts, normal pizza, etc.), chicken variations (nuggets, tenders, wings). Basically nothing too fancy.

I thought about wrapping the surface of the plate in plastic wrap but I feel like the food would get stuck to the wrap. Then I thought about aluminum but I’m pretty sure that’s a hazard. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Aluminum foil is fantastic if you're bored and want to watch some fireworks right in your own kitchen.

Comment: That’s what I figured

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to avoid doing dishes is to not use dishes.

Dish hack: **Eatable dishes**. This is not original but inspired from advertising which suggests crackers, rusks, toasted bread, pita were "eatable dishes." That changed my consumption of dish detergent by a significant amount.

Dish hack: **Parchment paper** (available in rolls) for baking. The beauty of parchment is that it can be re-used, withstand high temperatures, is somewhat water resistant and it can be disposable. Lay your pizza, melts, fried chicken, and fries right on top of a sheet covering the platter. It's great in a microwave unless you like soup.

You'll want to clean the microwave/convection oven interior occasionally; but, your question was about dishes. : )

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I like the eatable dish idea and I never would’ve thought of it myself

Comment: For many kinds of food you can fold your paper up and over and close the top and ends, this will not work with pizza's but it does with fish and most chicken variations.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks. I’ll be sure to keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

I use bounty paper towels as a plate and put that in the microwave. BOOM, eat and throw away the 'plate'.